# copy field from one component to another via modal - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two components, the main one that is called first and the other that is the content of the modal that is called second, in the first component I have an input with a "+" button that when I click it is loading a modal and inside the modal I am loading the second component where it loads a pagination with its respective records and each record appears with the "+" until there, well, **what I need is that when I give any record that appears with the "+" sign, I copy the content from the field "name" to the input of the first component and I close the modal**

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-thunder-zqqlx?file=/src/App.js

First

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {Modal, ModalBody, ModalFooter} from 'reactstrap';
import Segundo from "./Segundo";

function Primero() {
  const [modalCategoria, setModalCategoria]=useState(false);
  const [frameworkSeleccionado, setFrameworkSeleccionado]=useState({
    id_articulo:'',
    nombre:''
  });
   
  const handleChange=e=>{
    const {name, value}=e.target;
    setFrameworkSeleccionado((prevState)=>({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }))
   console.log(frameworkSeleccionado);
  }
 
  const abrirCerrarModalCategoria=()=>{
    setModalCategoria(!modalCategoria);
  }
 
    return (
   <div className="content-wrapper">   
    <section className="content">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        
     <label>Categoría:</label>
     <div class="input-group">
     <br/>
     <button className='btn btn-info'  onClick={()=>abrirCerrarModalCategoria()}><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
     <input type="text" className="form-control" name="categoria" onChange={handleChange} readOnly/>
     <br/>
     </div>
            <div>

<Modal isOpen={modalCategoria}>
<ModalBody>
   <Segundo /> 
 </ModalBody>
 <ModalFooter>
   <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=>abrirCerrarModalCategoria()}>Cancelar</button>
 </ModalFooter>
</Modal>
            </div>
      </div>
    </section>
   
  </div>
     )
    }
  
export default Primero
```

Second

```js
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import axios from 'axios';


function Segundo() {
  
  const baseUrlAd = "https://www.inventarios.gemcont.com/apiGemcont/inventarios/categorias/"; 
  const [data, setData]=useState([]);
  const [setFrameworkSeleccionado]=useState({
    id_categoria:'',
    nombre:''
  });

   
  const peticionGet =async() =>{
    await axios.get(baseUrlAd)
    .then(response=>{
     setData(response.data);
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
    })

  }

  const seleccionarFramework=(framework, caso)=>{
    setFrameworkSeleccionado(framework);
  } 

  useEffect(()=>{
   
       peticionGet();  
   
   },[])

  

  
  const columnas =[
    {
      title:'NOMBRE',
      field:'nombre'
    },
    {
      title:"ID",
      field: "id_categoria",
      
    }

  ];

  

    return (
  <div>
    <section className="content">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        
        <div className="row">
        
          <div className="col-md-12">

         
            <div>
              
            <MaterialTable   
     
columns={columnas}
data={data}
title=""
backIconButtonText='Página anterior'
pagination
fixedHeader

actions={[
     {
       icon : 'add',
       tooltip: 'Agregar',
       onClick: (event, framework)=>seleccionarFramework(framework, "Agregar")
    }
]}
options={{
  actionsColumnIndex: -1
}}
options={{
 actionsCellStyle: {
 },

}}
localization={{
    header:{
    actions: 'ACCIONES'
    
  },
  body:{ 
    emptyDataSourceMessage:'No hay registros que mostrar',
    
   },
   
}}

/>
           </div>
       
          </div>

         
        </div>   

      </div>
    </section>
   
  </div>
     )
    }

export default Segundo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code. Let me try to explain what I've found. I think that what you want is in [this corrected sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/copy-field-from-modal-v4xef)

First, to pass the data from the Modal to the parent component, you should use some communication between components. I should use a callback which I 've called `onSelect`

The parent component should handle that event:

```
const handleSelected = (selectedFramework) => {
    setFrameworkSeleccionado((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      nombre: selectedFramework.nombre
    }));
    setModalCategoria(false);
};
```

and then you should pass it to the child component:

```
<Segundo onSelect={handleSelected} />
```

The Modal component (Second) should get that callback:

```
function Segundo(props) {
  const { onSelect } = props;
  ...
```

and then, instead of using an internal state for the second component, it should use that callback:

```
const seleccionarFramework = (framework, caso) => {
    onSelect(framework);
};
```